# I need a dynamic List of Months (with first and last day) for a given date range, SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date

My code below works if @EndDate is set to anything within 2015, but when it is a date beyond the calendar year of @StartDate it stops at 12-31-2015.  Can someone please help me out, I'd like to be able to use this to get all months in between a user defined date range.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @EndDate DATE


set @StartDate = '1/1/2015' 
set @EndDate =  '12/31/2016'



SELECT 
    cast(dateadd(m, month-1, @StartDate) as date) begin_month,
    cast(dateadd(m, month, dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, @StartDate), -1)) as date) end_month
FROM (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) x(month)
WHERE 
    cast(dateadd(m, month-1, @StartDate) as date) >= @StartDate
and
    cast(dateadd(m, month, dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, @EndDate), -1)) as date) <= @EndDate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Instead of using just 12 rows, try using more rows. Here, I created a Tally Table up to 10,000 rows. Then, use `TOP` to limit the number of rows, depending on `DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1`. With that, you no longer need to add a `WHERE` clause:

```sql
DECLARE @StartDate  DATE,
        @EndDate    DATE

SELECT  @StartDate  = '20150101',
        @EndDate    = '20161231'

;WITH E1(N) AS( -- 10 ^ 1 = 10 rows
    SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b), -- 10 ^ 2 = 100 rows
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b), -- 10 ^ 4 = 10,000 rows
CteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(MONTH, @startDate, @endDate) + 1)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
)
SELECT 
    begin_month = DATEADD(MONTH, N-1, @startDate),
    end_month   = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, N, @startDate))
FROM CteTally
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/498498)</kbd>

Comment: Mahalo! Very slick too.